# Как собрать html?

Tags: html, css, gulp

Я собираю проект вообще галпом. Но до сегодняшнего дня у меня был 1 html и к нему 1 файл со стилями, при билде они благополучно перенаправлялись в dist. Сейчас у меня в проекте 2 html и соответственно к каждому свой файл со стилями. Как это по умному в продакшн сбилдить?

Comment: как вы собираете файлы для одной страницы, так собирайте для всех, можно код сборщика?

Comment: ну то есть я просто могу все html и стили к каждому из них перенести в продакшн? не объединяя как-то или что то еще

Comment: а как вы `html` собрались объединять?  для каждого `html` свои стили и все, больше по сути ничего ( для вас ) не нужно. А зачем вам галп, у вас стили на каком-нибудь `scss`?

Comment: да, sass или scss

Comment: покажите свой галпфайл (те части, которые касаются вопроса) и опишите что именно не получается.